# How to set value to null when Arraylist gets exhausted.?

Tags: java, arraylist

I m working on java.
i m trying below piece of code

```
public Proxy getNextElement() {

  Iterator<Element> itr = elementsToUse.iterator();
  if (proxiesToUse != null ){

      while (itr.hasNext()) {
        elementToReturn = itr.next();
        if(usedElements.contains(elementToReturn)==false){
           usedElements.add(elementToReturn);
           break;
        }
      }
     return elementToReturn;
   }else{
     Proxy nextElementToReturn = getNextProxy();
     return nextElementToReturn;
   }
}
```

now i want to throw the exception when `itr.hasNext()` will be false but the problem i m getting is because of while loop, when `itr.hasNext()`  gets false,the last value set to elementToReturn remains as it is and it is returned as it is but i want to return null when the list of `elementsToUse` has no more elements..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no condition to check before setting **elementToReturn** to null, then you can set elementToReturn to false directly after while loop.

```
public Proxy getNextElement() {    
    Iterator<Element> itr = elementsToUse.iterator();   
    if (proxiesToUse != null ){        
        while (itr.hasNext()) {         
            elementToReturn = itr.next();         
            if(usedElements.contains(elementToReturn)==false){            
               usedElements.add(elementToReturn);            
               break;         
            }       
        }   
     elementToReturn = null;
     return elementToReturn;    
    }else{      
        Proxy nextElementToReturn = getNextProxy();      
        return nextElementToReturn;    
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just return your values differently

```
   public Proxy getNextElement() {
        Iterator itr = elementsToUse.iterator();
        if (proxiesToUse != null) {
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                elementToReturn = itr.next();
                if (usedElements.contains(elementToReturn) == false) {
                    usedElements.add(elementToReturn);
                    return elementToReturn;
                }
            }
            return null;
        } else {
            Proxy nextElementToReturn = getNextProxy();
            return nextElementToReturn;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like following

```
        boolean condition = true;
        while (condition) {
        elementToReturn = itr.next();
        condition = itr.hasNext(); //condition to check next element present
        if(usedElements.contains(elementToReturn)==false){
           usedElements.add(elementToReturn);
           break;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version of your code which does the same thing. I assume that usedElements is a Set as duplicates are not allowed.

```
public Proxy getNextElement() {
    if (proxiesToUse == null) return getNextProxy();
    for (Element element : elementToUse)
        if (usedElements.add(element)) return element;
    return null;
}
```